# Illustrate difference in withContext behavior when dispatcher changes vs when it doesn't

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The Kotlin [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) for `withContext` say

> This function uses dispatcher from the new context, shifting execution of the block into the different thread if a new dispatcher is specified, and back to the original dispatcher when it completes. Note that the result of withContext invocation is dispatched into the original context in a cancellable way with a prompt cancellation guarantee, which means that if the original coroutineContext, in which withContext was invoked, is cancelled by the time its dispatcher starts to execute the code, it discards the result of withContext and throws CancellationException.

> The cancellation behavior described above is enabled if and only if the dispatcher is being changed. For example, when using withContext(NonCancellable) { ... } there is no change in dispatcher and this call will not be cancelled neither on entry to the block inside withContext nor on exit from it.

I've tried to design code that illustrates the difference between cancellation behavior when the dispatcher is being changed vs when it's not changed by `withContext`.  But I'm unable to duplicate the expected difference described in the docs.

I see the same cancellation behavior whether I switch dispatchers or not.

Not switching dispatcher with `withContext`:

```kt
val scope: CoroutineScope = object : CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher() + Job()
}
scope.run {
    val dispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()
    val job1 = launch {
        println(1)
        try {
            withContext(NonCancellable) {
                println(2)
                delay(50)
            }
            println(3)
            withContext(CoroutineName("Foo")) { // <-- Not switching dispatcher
                println(4)
                withContext(NonCancellable) {
                    delay(100)
                }
                println(5)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e)
        }
        println(6)
    }
    val job2 = launch {
        println(7)
        delay(10)
        job1.cancel()
    }
    println(8)
    joinAll(job1, job2)
    println(9)
}
```

Output:

```
1
8
7
2
3
kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: StandaloneCoroutine was cancelled; job="coroutine#41":StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@6c57dbdd
6
9
```

Switching dispatcher with `withContext`:

```kt
val scope: CoroutineScope = object : CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher() + Job()
}
scope.run {
    val dispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()
    val job1 = launch {
        println(1)
        try {
            withContext(NonCancellable) {
                println(2)
                delay(50)
            }
            println(3)
            withContext(dispatcher) { // <--- Switching dispatcher
                println(4)
                withContext(NonCancellable) {
                    delay(100)
                }
                println(5)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e)
        }
        println(6)
    }
    val job2 = launch {
        println(7)
        delay(10)
        job1.cancel()
    }
    println(8)
    joinAll(job1, job2)
    println(9)
}
```

Output:

```
1
8
7
2
3
kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: StandaloneCoroutine was cancelled; job="coroutine#41":StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@1f381518
6
9
```

I think what the above comparison shows is that `withContext` will throw an CancellationException when entering the `withContext` block, whether or not the dispatcher is switched.  But this contradicts the docs.

What am I missing?  Am I misunderstanding the docs?

Comment: "I've tried to design code that illustrates the difference between cancellation behavior when the dispatcher is being changed vs when it's not" - please show us what you have so far.

Comment: @Dai Will do.  It was quite messy, that's why I didn't include it.  But I'll clean it up and add to the post.

Comment: You missed this part `It immediately checks for cancellation of the resulting context and throws CancellationException if it is not active`. Also `withContext` will not throw `JobCancellationException` with `NonCancellable` in this case because `NonCancellable` is always active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the docs is that `withContext` won't introduce its own suspension points at the start and end unless you switch dispatchers. All other suspendable functions continue to work as usual and can be cancelled.

So, here's a test that you're looking for. There are two identical blocks of non-suspendable code, the first one is in a `withContext` that doesn't switch dispatchers and the 2nd one switches to `IO`. The first block always runs to completion, and then immediately after that you see the job was cancelled.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers.IO
import java.lang.Thread.currentThread
import java.lang.Thread.sleep
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS
import kotlin.concurrent.thread
import kotlin.system.measureNanoTime
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis

fun main() {
    val job = GlobalScope.launch {
        withContext(CoroutineName("foo")) {
            val rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current()
            val sum = (1..100_000_000).sumOf { rnd.nextInt() }
            println("Same dispatcher sum = $sum")
        }
        withContext(IO) {
            val rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current()
            val sum = (1..100_000_000).sumOf { rnd.nextInt() }
            println("Changed dispatcher sum = $sum")
        }
    }
    job.invokeOnCompletion { cause -> println("job completed with $cause") }
    job.cancel()
    currentThread().join()
}
```

Example of output:

```
Same dispatcher sum = 1660606514
job completed with kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: StandaloneCoroutine was cancelled; job=StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelled}@40f092d6
```

#### Update

As pointed out by OP, my program has a race due to which the first `withContext` misses the cancellation signal at the start. If we add `sleep()` to the start of the `GlobalScope.launch` block, we get cancellation before entering the first `withContext`.

Given this correction, I would then say the docs are wrong, specifically this sentence:

> The cancellation behavior described above is enabled if and only if the dispatcher is being changed.

It seems that actually, the behavior is enabled in all cases *except* when you use the `NonCancellable` job in the context. The next sentence of the docs gives a correct description of the specific example given:

> For example, when using `withContext(NonCancellable) { ... }` there is no change in dispatcher and this call will not be cancelled neither on entry to the block inside withContext nor on exit from it.

But, the generalization to any context that doesn't switch the dispatcher, appears to be wrong.

#### Update... Again

I also tried using `withContext(Job())`, breaking the inheritance of the current job (which is cancelled) into the `withContext` block. In this case there is again no cancellation. So the behavior seems to be pretty complicated, the `coroutineScope.isActive` flag isn't heeded, but `job.isActive` is, where `job` refers to the job passed in `withContext`.

Since the actual behavior seems to be self-contradictory, it's hard to say whether the bug is in the documentation or in the implementation.

Comment: Thanks @marko-topolnik.  I was hoping you'd respond, because I've learned more from your answers about coroutines than anyone else on Stack Overflow.  I made a slight modification to the code you offered - I sleep the launch by 1 second to give the main thread time to cancel the job before the first `withContext` executes.  And I put a try-catch around the first `withContext`.  A `CancellationException` is thrown.  But it's thrown by the first withContext.  Not the second.  Does this not show that cancellation isn't caused by the second `withContext` switching dispatcher?

Comment: Does it not show that cancellation of `job` is being checked at entry to the first `withContext`, even though the `withContext` isn't switching dispatcher?  This is the behavior that, from the docs, I'd expect only from the second `withContext`.

Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/lgtout/420def74f57464c5716b3835c01d7953)

Comment: Actually, I just tried my modifications of your code but without `sleep` within `launch`.  Running it has the same result - `CancellationException` is thrown by the first `withContext`, not the second, in contradiction with the docs.

Comment: Indeed, seems the docs are wrong and the behavior they describe applies exclusively to when you use `NonCancellable`, and not in general, whenever you don't change dispatchers.